# Javascript unsafe references to variable

Tags: javascript

The code below doesn't work the way I want. I think the problem is probably related to unsafe reference.

```js
var values = { "key1": "val1", "key2": "val2" };

const properties = {};
for (key in values) {
  properties[key] = {
    get: () => values[key],
    set: (val) => {
      values[key] = val
    }
  };

}
console.log(properties["key1"].get()); // Result should be val1 but it prints val2
```

How can I run the above code as I want?

Comment: `key` currently is a global, so when `get: () => values[key]` executes, key will always be the last key from the object... try `for ( let key in values )`

Comment: 1. Don't use implicit globals. 2. Consider using a linter like ESLint which saves you from common mistakes like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var values = { "key1": "val1", "key2": "val2" };

const properties = {};
for (const key in values) {
  properties[key] = {
    get: () => values[key],
    set: (val) => {
      values[key] = val
    }
  };

}
console.log(properties["key1"].get());
```

as per Jaromanda X told in the comment, the variable `key` is initiating as the global variable, and the global variable holds the last entry of the object, so try by making the `key` as a variable of for loop so, for each iterate of for loop it holds the value of `key` as a local variable, please check the above snippet